# Finding orthogonal basis of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A is a 3 by 3 symmetric matrix and {2,3} is the set of eigenvalues, and ${(1~~~2~~~3)^T}$ spans 2-eigenspace of A. Find an orthogonal basis of 3-eigenspace of A

I suppose I should get two basis of 3-eigenspace of A.

A also satisfies
$$A 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3\\
\end{pmatrix}
=2\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

A is also invertible but I am not sure how to use those information to find the orthogonal basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The spectral theorem tells us that $A$ has at least one basis of orthonormal eigenvectors; one of the eigenvectors must be parallel to $(1,2,3)^T$.

Use this to argue that **every** vector that is orthogonal to $(1,2,3)^T$ must be an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $3$. In other words, we can conclude that the eigenspace of $A$ associated with $3$ is the *orthogonal complement* of the span of $\{(1,2,3)^T\}$